# ng-select is sending "NULL" instead of an empty string when placeholder option is left selected

Tags: angular, typescript

When performing a search for inventory the user has a few options to refine their search. All the options are not required but if one is not selected ng-select interprets the selection as "NULL" which the server does not handle on the GET request because it is instead expecting an empty string. This can be resolved by having no placeholder text and instead an empty string but obviously that hurts the user experience. I need a way to pass an empty string for the ng-select when nothing is selected while still having placeholder text.

```
    <ng-select placeholder="{{'Select year' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedHeavyDutyYear" [items]="searchHeavyDutyYears" [clearable]="false" (change)="populateHeavyDutyMakes()" [disabled]="isLoading" dropdownPosition="bottom"></ng-select>
    <ng-select placeholder="{{'Select make' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedHeavyDutyMake" [items]="searchHeavyDutyMakes" [clearable]="false" (change)="populateHeavyDutyModels()" [disabled]="isLoading || !selectedHeavyDutyYear" dropdownPosition="bottom"></ng-select>
    <ng-select placeholder="{{'Select model' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedHeavyDutyModel" [items]="searchHeavyDutyModels" [clearable]="false" (change)="searchHeavyDutyYmmIfDesktop()" [disabled]="isLoading || !selectedHeavyDutyMake" dropdownPosition="bottom"></ng-select>
```

I have seen this as a common problem and stumbled across http://jsfiddle.net/CB5um/ as a solution but I am struggling with how to write it as a directive that I could add on to any select in Angular 7.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your TS and replace NULL with empty string before calling API.

```
if (!this.selectedHeavyDutyYear) {
  this.selectedHeavyDutyYear = "";
}
```

Comment: So we are currently using something just like this for this specific case but were trying to find a way of implementing a directive so as to just add it on to every select so as to prevent future bugs when we add new selects like this.